# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Invalid length parameter passed

Tags: sql-server

The situation:

I have a database with a bunch of images and i'm exporting them into folders. There is a image column and a source image column. In the source image column most of the  records look like this:

```
Column 1                   Column 2
C:\blah\blah\test.pdf      BlobField
```

When the files export i want to name them test.pdf and i do that by:

```
 RIGHT(SOURCE_DOCUMENT, (CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SOURCE_DOCUMENT),0))-1)
```

Which works great.

But in some of the records they just look like

```
Column 1
Message.txt
```

And i get an Invalid Length Parameter passed error, because i guessing it doesnt have a \.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append `\` at the end of `SOURCE_DOCUMENT` to prevent error :

```
SELECT RIGHT(SOURCE_DOCUMENT, (CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SOURCE_DOCUMENT) +'\', 0))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE expression to get one value (your `RIGHT(...)` function) if the column has a `\` character, and a different value (presumably the whole string) if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check is there `\` in the name of the document and return it unmodified in case it is file name only:

```
IIF(CHARINDEX('\', SOURCE_DOCUMENT) > 0, RIGHT(SOURCE_DOCUMENT, (CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SOURCE_DOCUMENT),0))-1), SOURCE_DOCUMENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` statement to achieve this:

```
SELECT  CASE
          WHEN CHARINDEX('\', SOURCE_DOCUMENT) > 0 THEN RIGHT(SOURCE_DOCUMENT, (CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(SOURCE_DOCUMENT),0))-1)
          ELSE SOURCE_DOCUMENT
        END AS SOURCE_DOCUMENT
```

This will utilise your `RIGHT(...)` statement where the column contains a backslash or just return the column where it does not.